# Show that there existe two polynomials $q$ and $r$ in $K[x]$ such that $f=qg+r$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> For a field $K$, we set $K[x]$ for the set of polynomials with the
>   variable $x$ and with coefficient in $K$. The notion of degree will be
>   taken as usual, that is, the greatest degree of $x$ that appears in a
>   polynomial. Given $f$ and $g$ in $K[x]$, where $g \not= 0$, show that
>   there existe two polynomials $q$ and $r$ in $K[x]$ such that $f=qg+r$
>   (division with remainder).

I would like to solve the problem myself, but I don't know how to begin. Are there someone who could give me a good hint to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the proof for integers. In this case, one looks at the set $I=\{a-bq\mid q\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, and uses the fact that $I^+=I\cap\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is nonempty and bounded below (hence, has a smallest element).

For $K[x]$, consider the set $I=\{f-gq\mid q\in K[x]\}$. Note that if $0\in I$ you are done. Otherwise consider $I^+=\{\deg(r)\mid r\in I\}$ and proceed like you would for integers.

**Theorem:** Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $b\neq 0$. Then there exist unique $q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$a=bq+r\;\;\;0\leq r<|b|.$$

*Proof:* We may assume that $b>0$ (after proving the statement for $b>0$, we have $a=(-b)q+r=b(-q)+r$ for $b<0$).

As above, we see that $I^+$ is nonempty and bounded below, so $I^+$ contains a least element $r$. Since $r\in I$, $r=a-bq$ for some $q$, so we get
$$a=bq+r$$
We now want to see that $0\leq r <b$. If not, say $k=r-b\geq 0$, then $k=a-b(q+1)\in I^+$ contradicting the minimality of $r$. Hence, $0\leq r<b$ as desired.

For uniqueness, assume $bq+r=a=bt+s$ where $0\leq r,s<b$. Then $b(q-t)=s-r$, so $b|(s-r)$. But, $-b<s-r<b$, forcing $s-r=0$. Thus, $s=r$ and $q=t$.

Comment: In the case $K[x]$, $I^+$ is he always define as $I^+=I\cap\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$?

Comment: It not clear that $I^+=I\cap\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}=\{\deg(r)\mid r\in I\}$. Can you explain this?

Comment: @J.G For $K[x]$, I did not define $I^+$ this way and I am not claiming the equality in you comment. The point is that the degrees of polynomial are nonnegative integers (except for $0$, to which I assign the degree $-\infty$.

Comment: Are you able to give me more help? I still do not know how to start.

Comment: @J.G. Above is a proof for integers. For polynomials, take $r(x)\in I$ of minimal degree in $I^+$.  The only nontrivial part to adapt is showing $\deg r<\deg b$. To do this, suppose $r(x)=r_mx^m+\cdots$ and $b(x)=b_nx^n+\cdots$ with $m\geq n$. Let $k(x)=r(x)-b_n^{-1}r_mx^{m-n}b(x)$. Then $k(x)\in I$ has smaller degree than $r(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

hint : prove that $K[x]$ is an euclidian domain